# add specific text to a customm fields with php (wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-fields

I want to add text "Genre:" to the beginning of this custom field

```
<?php the_field('im_genre'); ?>
```

the reason that i dont simply add something like this

```
 <li>Genre:<?php the_field('im_genre'); ?> </li>
```

is that i dont want to this text be shown when there isnt this field for a post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the field exists and then display your HTML element.

```
<?php if( get_field('im_genre') ): ?>
    <li>Genre:<?php the_field('im_genre'); ?> </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it by using the "acf/format_value" hook.

```
add_filter('acf/format_value', 'reFormatValue', 20, 3);
function reFormatValue($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $data = [
    // list of field keys to format
    'field_XXXXXXX' => 'XXX:',
    'im_genre' => 'Genre:',
    // etc...
  ];
  $keys = array_keys($data);
  if (in_array($field['key'], $keys)) {
    $value = $keys[$field['key']] . $value;
  }
  return $value;
}
```

add this to your functions.php (active theme folder) or any active plugins